# std::sample() returns the same elements every time

Tags: c++

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string in = "hgfedcba";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::string out;
        std::sample(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out),
                    5, std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
        std::cout << "five random letters out of " << in << " : " << out << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
five random letters out of hgfedcba : hgeda
five random letters out of hgfedcba : hgeda
five random letters out of hgfedcba : hgeda
five random letters out of hgfedcba : hgeda
five random letters out of hgfedcba : hgeda
```

How to fix? I have tried reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample, but it is a little bit complicated

Comment: Your random generation is faulty and ineffective.

Comment: This is not an issue with `std::sample`, it's an issue with how you use your RNG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time in your loop you are constructing a new random engine with a default `random_device`. The standard library allows implementations of `random_device` to generate the same sequence of values for every instance, so your code could produce the same results in every iteration. In other words, given the current specification of `random_device`, you can think of [this](https://xkcd.com/221/) as a conforming implementation.

A simple fix is to lift the construction of the generator out of the loop:

```
auto rng = std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()};
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        // ...
        std::sample(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out),
                    5, rng);
        // ...
}
```

Comment: @PasserBy I don't blame you. I've been itching to use that in a an answer for a while, but I've refrained so far ;)

Comment: @PasserBy Heck, why not, might as well go for it. Hopefully this doesn't attract too many down-votes :p

Answer (score 1):

You should not be making a new engine within your loop. Make the engine outside your loop, then just invoke it within the loop.

```
int main()
{
    std::string in = "hgfedcba";
    std::mt19937 mt{std::random_device{}()};
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::string out;
        std::sample(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out), 5, mt);
        std::cout << "five random letters out of " << in << " : " << out << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output

```
five random letters out of hgfedcba : gfdcb
five random letters out of hgfedcba : hgdba
five random letters out of hgfedcba : gedcb
five random letters out of hgfedcba : gedba
five random letters out of hgfedcba : gfeda
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually a random generation is set up like this

```cpp
int main() {
    std::random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()

    std::string in = "hgfedcba";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::string out;
        std::sample(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out),
                    5, gen);
        std::cout << "five random letters out of " << in << " : " << out << '\n';
    }
}
```